# Remove spacing between images in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, mnist

I want to display MNIST images as a composite image using matplotlib. Right now it is displaying the individual images on a horizontal plane (1 row, x columns) but there is whitespace between each image.

How can I bring the images right next to each other (removing the vertical whitespace between each MNIST image) so it looks like 1 single image?

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
for x in range(5):
    digit = train_images[x]
    plt.box(False)
    plt.subplot(1, 5, x+1)
    plt.imshow(digit)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.grid(b=None)
#plt.title('50419 -- my Name', loc='center')
plt.show()
```

This is what the current output looks like:

[image: current output]

Comment: You probably want an ImageGrid: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_grid.ImageGrid.html

Comment: ... or https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/simple_axesgrid.html

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I was able to fix it with just a single line of code:

```
plt.tight_layout(pad=0.00)
```

This brought the images right next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try with this 'fig' method:

`fig.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0)`

First you would have to create a fig and an axis:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 5)
```